# If my commercial application includes a GPL licensed Nuget package, do I need to open source my application?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3

Usually the nuget package is a dll after it is released. Do I need to open source the application that references it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a library that is released under the GPL license, then the entire project needs to be available under a GPL-compatible open-source license. The fact that you retrieve a compiled version using a package manager doesn't change anything in that.